# Is reasoning an english gerund implying an awake,well mind.?

Tags: logic, semantics

To Quote the Tag :

Logic is the study of formal systems of reasoning, especially of the deductive variety.

Reasoning implies the subject ie The mind.

If the mind is implied then perhaps only verb-nouns are appropriate to define or be applied to the mind.

The mind is only "known" through the results of thinking which is actioned (outward) or contemplative(inward).

http://people.bu.edu/tylert/Latin/gerundsvsgerundives.html

Comment: Please note that we're not here to make philosophy, and we don't like questions with no definite answers. Your question reads a lot like 'How do you like my thoughts?', which for at least two reasons doesn't fall under 'good question' here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see why you *could* reason this way, but *gerund* is a technical term reserved for the study of grammar, and I don't think that this kind of usage slippage works until its already ratified by a scholarly community.

Essentially all you're doing is rephrasing the first statement.

As far as I can see you're using the Aristotelean Syllogistic reasoning; but the fact that you're slipping across different domains of discourse makes the reasoning shaky; and in fact shows up one of the weakness of syllogistic reasoning when *meaning* & *context* is not taken into account.

Another example of this is:

> God is One
>
> One is a Number
>
> Therefore, God is a Number.

Of course, God is not a Number in Islamic theology. The mistake occurs in the meaning of One in both the first & second statements. They belong to different domains of discourse.

There is a way in which this dissonance of discourse makes sense and that is the use of metaphor in literature/poetry where two unlike ideas are yoked together. "Reason is a Gerund" could be the beginning of a poem where the body of it elaborates on those two central ideas. But then this has nothing to do with philosophy per se.

Comment: Do you mean that in philosophy discourse the term :'to reason' does not mean to actively process information according to logical process of the discipline or collective; or the word "gerund" is not applicable to terms. Can reason be inactive if the mind is making sense of change in circumstance, past resent or future?To not be reasoned in my collective is to be any of the following; oblivious, disengaged, reactive(emotional), automaton, reflexive, without empathy(unkind) or stuck.

Comment: To reason can mean what you suggest ie 'active process' - but of course there are other views. Its your use of gerund in this context that I'm suggesting is inappropriate here. I can see why you made that association, but the association is more akin to that of metaphor than that used in syllogistic reasoning which is what you look like you're attempting. I'm not sure what you mean by *collective*. Perhaps the key of your concern appears to be here threefold, correct me if I am wrong:

Comment: a. Is it active or inactive/static. b. How is reason to be distinguished from emotion, c. lack of reasoning to be distinguished from lack of emotion - ie oblivious, automaton, reflexive etc.

Comment: Actually, now looking at the first part of your question, there is another concern there which I assume set off your train of thought: How can one make sense of the aphorism (in the Giorgias?) "Happiness is to be active in reason", but as you say 'reason implies activity'. So the question is how does one resolve the tension & difference between these two insights. If these are in fact your concerns then I encourage you either to edit this question, or to ask a more appropriately focused one.

Comment: God is One is not a complete sentence is one of, is one with is one as apposed to two.

Comment: @Lisa: In Islamic theology, One here simply means unique, singular, non-comparable etc. Hence it can't be the first in a series of terms. Like one of, or one with.

Comment: i am thinking "only". That is difficult because I am one with the trinity 3/3 =1 thanks for your feedback I have much to ponder.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9645/discussion-between-lisa-and-mozibur-ullah)